# $f(x) = \inf_{k \in \mathbb N} k |x - x_k |$ is continuous if $x_k$ has no accumulation point

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

I need to show that if $(x_n)$ is a real valued sequence with no accumulation point, then the function $f(x) = \inf_{k \in \mathbb N} k | x - x_k |$ is continuous. I also need to find a sequence that makes $f$ not continuous, but I haven't really worked on that part yet.

My approach so far is the following: fix $y \in \mathbb R$. As $(x_n)$ has no accumulation points, it is unbounded hence $k|y - x_k|$ is unbounded. For every $M \in \mathbb R$, this means the set $\{k|y-x_k|\} \cap [0, M]$ must be finite. If we set $M := |y - x_1|$, the set is inhabited and the minimum of the is equal to $f(y)$. But then $f$ is the minimum of a finite set of continuous functions, hence $f$ is continuous.

I feel very uneasy about the reasoning though, in particular that our choice of $M$ depends on $y$. I would appreciate some guidance on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You correctly identified that the goal is to express $f$ as a $\min$ of a finite number of functions.

We note that not only is $x_k$ unbounded, but $|x_k| \to \infty$.

Suppose $|x| \le M$. Note that if we choose some large enough $K$ such that
$|x-x_1| \le 2 |x-x_k|$ for $k \ge K$, then
$f(x) = \min_{k \in \{1,...,K\}} k|x-x_k|$ from which continuity follows on $|x| < M$.

Note that $|x-x_1| \le M+|x_1|$ and $|x_k|-M \le |x-x_k|$, hence if
$M+|x_1| \le 2|x_k| -2M$, or
$|x_k| \ge {1 \over 2} (3M+|x_1|)$ then the inequality is satisfied. Hence we
can choose $K$ such that this is satisfied.